# Looking for an off-the-shelf package for switching a small pump based on PWM signal from Hall effect sensor

Tags: pwm, motor-controller, hall-effect

I'm an electrician trying to solve a problem at home, but I'm a little out of my depth.

I'm looking for an off-the-shelf module into which I can feed a PWM signal from a Hall effect sensor, in order to switch a small pump on and off. I need provision for a potentiometer to set the trigger point for switching the pump, as I can't reprogram any chip myself.

It would also be nice to be able to set a 'dwell' time. By this I mean another pot or jumper setting, so that the PWM signal needs to be on for X seconds before switching the pump off. If not, I'll have to do this with another module.

I don't necessarily need a relay with a 10A 240V DPDT capacity as I can add this later, but it would be nice if it comes with one. It would also be nice if it had an on-board power supply for 240V, but I feel like I'm asking a lot now :P

I've found [this one](https://czh-labs.com/products/panel-mount-momentary-switch-pulse-signal-control-latching-spdt-relay-module12v), but it doesn't seem to have provision for a pot anywhere - let alone dwell time.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Questions re off the shelf solutions are off topic for this site. People tend to vote to close even when this is part of a design problem. If you can recast your  question as a not 'where can I buy' one it may survive.

Comment: OR go to http://www.piclist.com , read the intro then join the mailing list via link at end.
 Then ask your question there and it very very likely will get well addressed.

Comment: Thanks Russell, I'll try to reframe the question.

Comment: @jay - Hi, Please be careful. With several of your recent edits, you changed a lot, but [edits *must not* change the meaning of the question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). Here your edit removed mention of PWM, removed mention of available power supply voltage & several other changes. I sense that you are keen to help (thanks!) but please "calm down" that enthusiasm and always remember - it's not *your* question, so you must not *change* it, only *clarify* (see previous link). I will rollback (undo) your edit. Thanks for helping :-)

Comment: @SamGibson - I will keep it in mind. I will skip or suggest to do something, but not alter those too much,
 Meantime, I thought; The question did have the word PWM. It may give a significant weight to the question. But, it was not any part of the real question, only causing confusion. Thus, the question could be removed due to the clarity problem. Anyway, thanks for the advice, not dropping a bomb on me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Split the job in two - current sensing and timing - and purchase industrial components. These will be DIN rail mounted so can be fitted in a consumer panel or separate DIN box.

Many of these are 24 V DC as this is the most common standard for industrial control automation. If you don't have 24 V DC available then you should search for mains-powered versions.

[image]

*Figure 1. A selection of current sensing relays from Google image search.*

Note that these ones are designed like current transformers and you pass the conductor to be monitored through the hole in the module. For higher sensitivity you can pass multiple turns through it.

[image]

*Figure 2. A selection of DIN rail timer modules.*

Timers are available in delay-on, delay-off and multifunction.

Comment: Note that this was written when @jay's edit was in place. I did not see the original question or the mention of PWM - if it is significant.

Comment: Thanks mate, I thought about current sensing, but there doesn't seem to be a great difference in current whether there's decent flow or none at all. The pump is running pressure compensated drip line, so it always seems to run at close to max current. The real issue is flow and I figured the best (also cheapest) way is with a hall effect sensor.

I''m happy to split the job with a timer, but it would be nice if there was a programming solution :)

Comment: You need to add that information into your question then.